# How to hide the prev and next arrow key

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to hide the arrow keys. So when the user clicks on the first image the previous arrow key will be hidden and only the next arrow key is visible and in the last image the next arrow key will be hidden and the previous arrow key is visible.
Please click on the full page view after click on the run code snippet

```js
function openModal() {
          document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
        }
        function closeModal() {
          document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
        }
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);
        function plusSlides(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }
        function currentSlide(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }
        function showSlides(n) {
          var i;
          var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
          var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
          var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
          if (n > slides.length) {
            slideIndex = 1
          }
          if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = slides.length
          }
          for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
          }
          for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
          dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
          captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }
```

```css
.modal {
      width: 58%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      position: fixed;
      display: none;
      background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
      margin-left: 300px;
      max-width: 779px;
      min-width: 779px;
    }
    .modal-content {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
    }
    .mySlides {
      display: none;
    }
    .mySlides {
      display: none;
    }
    .cursor {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .cursor {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .prev {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      top: -149px;
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: -50px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      left: -10%;
    }
    .next {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      top: -149px;
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: -50px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      left: 600px;
```

```html
 <tr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <td>
          <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900" width="250" height="164"
              onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
        </td>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <td>
          <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x900" width="250" height="164"
              onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
        </td>
      </div>
  </tr>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal modal-visible">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
      <div class="mySlides">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900" style="width: 98%;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 109px;">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x900" style="width: 98%;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 109px;">
      </div>
      <a class="prev" id="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just completed @Ghislain Bergeron's answer and corrected some missing parts in your CSS and HTML codes.

```js
function openModal() {
    document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}
function closeModal() {
    document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }  

    if (slideIndex == 1) {
        document.getElementById("next1").hidden = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("next1").hidden = true;
    }

    if (slideIndex == (slides.length)) {
        document.getElementById("prev1").hidden = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prev1").hidden = true;
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```

```css
.modal {
    width: 58%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
    margin-left: 300px;
    max-width: 779px;
    min-width: 779px;
}
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}
.cursor {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cursor {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.prev {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: -149px;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    left: -10%;
}
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: -149px;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    left: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css"/>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
<body>
    <tr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <td>
              <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900" width="250" height="164"
                  onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
            </td>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <td>
              <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x900" width="250" height="164"
                  onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
            </td>
          </div>
      </tr>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal modal-visible">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
          <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900" style="width: 98%;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 109px;">
          </div>
          <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x900" style="width: 98%;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 109px;">
          </div>
          <a class="prev" id="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
          <a class="next" id="next1" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have 9 images in the gallery, where should I change in the code to disable the left arrow in first image and disable right arrow in the last image. Sorry for asking stupid question, I am very new to js.

Comment: The js code is ready for various images, even for only one image. Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah. When I put the function nothing is showing in the popup. But worked for only two images.

Comment: You should modify your HTML according to the logic you are following. For instance, one thing you should do is to modify the `onclick` events for each image saying `onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)"`, `onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)"`, `onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)"` ... `onclick="openModal();currentSlide(n)"`. There are other modifications you should do for the rest of the HTML page, but the `showSlides()` function wouldn't require to change, at least not too much.

Answer (score 1):

Assign an ID to the next button, lets say "next1", then add this code at the end of the function showSlides(). You can initialize prev1 and next1 by adding attribute hidden="true" on the prev1 link and add the attribute hidden="false" on next1 assuming you have more than one slide. It can be something like this.

```js
if (slideIndex > 1) {
    document.getElementById("prev1").hidden = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById("prev1").hidden = true;
}

if (slideIndex < (slides.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("next1").hidden = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById("next1").hidden = true;
}
```